# ScrollView inside ViewPager does not scroll on Android 4.x

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a problem that seems to only impact Android 4.x versions and may be also device specific (i.e. it does not exist on my Huawei G630@4.3, but do exists on a Samsung Ace2@4.4.4).
I have a `ScrollView` that contains a `RelativeLayout` that has 4 `CardView`s. Now on some 4.x devices, the scroll event simply does not happen when I try to scroll beginning from a card. If I touch the small padding between the cards or above **the first** card (and not **between** any two) and the device screen, I can scroll the content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/metricsContainerCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/metrics"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/metrics"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/projectCircleBackgroundShadow"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/warningsContainerCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/metricsContainerCard"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bug_color"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/warnings"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/projectCircleBackgroundShadow"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/topWarningsContainerCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/warningsContainerCard"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/top_warnings"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/topWarnings"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/projectCircleBackgroundShadow"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/topCriticalItemsContainerCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/topWarningsContainerCard"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/top_critical_items"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/topCriticalItems"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/projectCircleBackgroundShadow"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

There isn't any problem on Android 5.x and 6.x.

**EDIT**

It seems that problem is not exclusively related to `CardView`, as I have another layout, and it also does not scroll even when I drag the screen by the custom view:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".projects.details.ProjectDetailsActivity_">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/projectName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Project name"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <c.f.q.a.projects.details.components.widgets.ProjectDetailWidget
                android:id="@+id/projectDetailWidget"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timelineWrapperLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/qualityTimelineCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/flipQualityTimelineButton"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/flip_to_cost"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:text="@string/project_timeline_title"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/projectQualityTimelineProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                        android:id="@+id/projectQualityTimeline"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:tag="@string/project_chart_tag"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/costTimelineCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/flipCostTimelineButton"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/flip_to_quality"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:text="@string/project_cost_timeline_title"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/projectCostTimelineProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                        android:id="@+id/projectCostTimeline"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:tag="@string/project_chart_tag"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/vcsChangeCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/expandVcsChangeButton"
                        android:layout_width="28dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/expand_chart"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:text="@string/project_vcschange_title"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/vcsChangeProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                    android:id="@+id/projectVcsChange"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:tag="@string/project_chart_tag"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/dtnosChangeCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/expandDtnosChangeButton"
                        android:layout_width="28dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/expand_chart"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:text="@string/project_systemchange_title"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/dtnosChangeProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                    android:id="@+id/projectDtnosChange"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:tag="@string/project_chart_tag"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/sensorNodeCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/expandSensornodeButton"
                            android:layout_width="28dp"
                            android:layout_height="28dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/expand_chart"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="@string/project_sensornode_title"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/sensorNodeProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.RadarChart
                        android:id="@+id/sensorNodeChart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="175dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:tag="@string/project_chart_tag"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/aggregateNodeCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/expandAggregateButton"
                            android:layout_width="28dp"
                            android:layout_height="28dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/expand_chart"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="@string/project_aggregatenode_title"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/aggregateNodeProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.RadarChart
                        android:id="@+id/aggregateNodeChart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="175dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:tag="@string/project_chart_tag"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I added the complete layout, and also here is an image for clarification (I marked the scrollable areas which I can drag):

[image: scrollable areas]

**EDIT2**

Maybe it is also important that these layouts are Fragments inside a `ViewPager`. Is it possible that the `ViewPager` prevents the `ScrollView` (and any other views inside it) gaining the focus / handling the touch events? The code for my `ViewPager` is this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/projectPager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

**EDIT3**

It seems the problem must be with `ViewPager` + `(Nested)ScrollView` (I tried to exchange the plain `ScrollView` with that, but without success). I created a dummy layout for my Fragment that only hosts a parent `NestedScrollView`, a `LinearLayout` and many big `TextView`s like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".projects.details.ProjectDetailsActivity_">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Project name"
        android:textSize="80sp"/>

... <!-- more TextViews come here -->
```

...and scrolling also doesn't work! Only at the very edge of the screen, as previously. I have no idea how can this happen...

Comment: From your edit it seems that it's not related to CardView - perhaps you could reedit to omit the CardView, and provide instead more information about the rest of your setup.

Comment: Did you try setting `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` attributes of the `CardView`?

Comment: Yes, I tried them, no luck. I edited my post with more details, maybe these can help.

Comment: @Sleeper9 ok see my edited answer

Comment: Tried that, still no luck. Can the fact cause this, that my `CardView`s get "populated" (e.g. more `View`s added) later on? I just made a very small sample with `ScrollView` containing only `TextView`s and `ImageView`s, and I can scroll the content.

Comment: Well you are on the right track - in any form of problem like this, the trick to solving it is to build up from a simple working example, adding bits as you go, moving towards the broken version. All of a sudden one change will break it, and you will know where to look, and what extra info to add to this question (or a self-answer)

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: No luck about this yet. As the problem appeared only on rather old devices so long, I gave up debugging. Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I had exactly the same problem. You are probably using a PageTransformer ViewPager animation.

Disabling the custom page transformer for < Android 4.1 solved it:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        // there are problems with this on 4.0.3, probably also on 4.1
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
    }
```

Your post and research saved me a lot of time, thank you.

**OTHER SOLUTION:**

If you like your animation, you can also try changing your DepthPageTransformer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214802/1310343c

Comment: I can't believe it... Many-many thanks, this solved my problem as well! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the 2 scrollable controls are competing with each other.

Use a `NestedScrollView` from the Support Library instead. It is designed to get around problems of this type.

It has many enhancements that lets it work with other scrollable controls, including the `ViewPager`, `RecyclerView` (as long as you call `.setNestedScrolling(true)`) and `CoordinatorLayout`.

Based on the above, I have been using this new class in all instances, and the scrolling within scrolling has been working perfectly. Our product is live with perfectly working `NestedScrollView` controls inside a `ViewPager`, some with embedded `RecyclerView` lists inside them as well.

Comment: Well, I exchanged `<ScrollView>` with `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>`, but still nothing has changed. :( I called `.setNestedScrolling(true)` as well. Is there something I need to set in the XML layout?

Comment: Ok sorry it didn't help in this case. Will leave this here in case of other readers. Community wiki so anyone can edit and improve.

Comment: But the problem must be here somewhere... As I wrote, my other Views inside the `ScrollView` neither respond to tap, pinch etc. events, so the ViewPager must be consuming the gesture somehow...

Answer (score 2):

For me this setup worked: I have a Coordinator layout which has below nested scrollview

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fillViewport = "true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <include layout="@layout/content_app_bar_search_patient_module"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and `<include layout="@layout/content_app_bar_search_patient_module"/>`has a viewpager which has fragment which contains again a nested scrollview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
.
.
.
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `ScrollView` must have `match_parent height` and first child of scrollview ( `LinearLayout` ) must have `wrap_content` height

Comment: I've tried that previously (I also left an `android:orientation="vertical"`in my sample by mistake), but did not help. I'm currently trying with Genymotion Google Nexus S@4.1.1.

Comment: @Sleeper9 give your xml layout complete .

Comment: I've edited my post, added the full layouts and an image for clarification!