# Scrollview inside Viewpager not scrolling once page is swiped

Tags: android

I am working on a reader app in which i have a layout containing ViewPager. In this ViewPager. This ViewPager contains Fragment whose layout file contains a ScrollView. This ScrollView is scrolling correctly in most of the devices but on a device its not scrolling correctly. Actually on application launch, ScrollView is scrolling but after viewpager is swiped, scrollview's scrolling stops working. I can't understand why this is happening only on one device.
**ViewPager Layout is below:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Half Girlfriend"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/visible"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/hide" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_x" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/page_status"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:onClick="clickViewpager" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/page_status"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_border"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="285"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/page_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/bottom_bar_color"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/page_level"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="283" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pages_col"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/page_level"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dynamic_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="25"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/of"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dynamic_no"
                android:text="of"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/static_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/of"
                android:text="284"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the Fragment's layout:**

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/getcontent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/getcontent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: try with NestedScrollview

Comment: I have tried this, but not working, even i tried to scroll the textview using setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());   method but not helping

Comment: add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  in viewpager

Comment: @DivyeshPatel above solution not working, Please help

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14435116/8164071)

Comment: @PriteshVadhiya your solution not working

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, there is nothing wrong with the code. Actually i was adding page transformer on Viewpager as

```
mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
```

but it does not work correctly in some android versions as solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827095/scrollview-inside-viewpager-does-not-scroll-on-android-4-x) post. It also not working correctly in Lollipop 5.1 and 5.1.1 so 
one can check for this also:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
        mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    }
```

If someone has a better solution then this, then please post.
I hope my solution help someone. Thanks to all for contribution.